# Invalid TYpe in Map

Tags: apex, trigger

Here i am trying to hard code the map

```
trigger Mapcls on Candidate__c (before insert) {

    Map<Country__c,Curtyp__c>mymap=new Map<Country__c,Curtyp__c>{'India'=>'Rupee','USA'=>'USDollar','Singapore'=>'SGDollar'};
        for(Candidate__c c:trigger.new)
    {
        c[0].Curtyp__c=mymap.get(Country__c);
    }

}
```

Curtyp__c is of multipicklist data type and country is of picklist type.

what could be the reason for error message .

**Update**

Here is the corrected code trigger Mapcls on Candidate__c (before insert) {

```
    Map<string,string>mymap=new Map<string,string>{'India'=>'Rupee','USA'=>'USDollar','Singapore'=>'SGDollar'};
    for(Candidate__c c:trigger.new)
    {

        c.Curtyp__c=mymap.get(c.Country__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are populating your Map with String Keys ('India') and String Values ('Rupee') but have defined the key as an sObject (Country__c) and value as an sObject (Curtyp__c)

So the values you are populating do not match what you have defined.

Simply change to `Map<String,String>`

Also this line will giver you an error `c[0].Curtyp__c=mymap.get(Country__c);` as Country__c does not exist. You need to use `c.Country__c` and since `c` is not a list, you do not use the `[0]` index as c is the variable name for a single instance in the loop

Comment: Map<string,string>mymap=new Map<Country__c,Curtyp__c>{'India'=>'Rupee','USA'=>'USDollar','Singapore'=>'SGDollar'};           Country__c,Curtyp__c are the field labels where can i define them.

Comment: trigger Mapcls on Candidate__c (before insert) {
    
    Map<string,string>mymap=new Map<string,string>{};
    Map<Country__c,Curtyp__c>mymap={'India'=>'Rupee','USA'=>'USDollar','Singapore'=>'SGDollar'};
        for(Candidate__c c:trigger.new)
    {
        c[0].Curtyp__c=mymap.get(Country__c);
    }

} is this correct

Answer (score -1):

Here is the corrected code trigger Mapcls on Candidate__c (before insert) {

```
Map<string,string>mymap=new Map<string,string>{'India'=>'Rupee','USA'=>'USDollar','Singapore'=>'SGDollar'};

    for(Candidate__c c:trigger.new)
{

    c.Curtyp__c=mymap.get(c.Country__c);
}
```

}

Comment: I am glad you finally got the code correct but this should be posted in your question as the final output as it is not an answer to your question but the result of your work do to an answer to your question

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This isn't really an answer to the question per se so I moved the content to your question. If Eric's answer helped you get there you should mark it as the correct answer.